# Office 365 Upload file to Document Library without using FileReader API

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-online, office-365, file-upload

I want a script in javascript that can upload a document to the document library.

I know that HTML5 Browsers can do this with ease because I can simply use the FileReader API but how do I do this for older non HTML5 browsers?

Comment: This require FileReader API which I have and already works but what of browsers without HTML5 support like ie9 downwards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery widget for do this.

http://paultavares.wordpress.com/2012/04/28/sharepoint-ui-widgets-upload-and-pickusers/

This plugin uses `SPServices`

```
$("#uploadDivContainer").SPControlUpload({
    listName:       "Shared Documents",
    onPageChange:   function(ev){

        // If we're done with the upload, then continue to show the
        // overlay, and fade out the area that contained the upload control.
        if (ev.state == 3 && ev.isUploadDone) {
            ev.hideOverlay = false;
            $('<div style="padding: 1em; width: 80%; margin: 3em auto;" class="ui-state-highlight">Upload Successful!!!</div>')
                .appendTo(uiUploadWidget.empty())
                .fadeOut(4000, function(){
                    $(this).remove();
                });

            // Reload files into viewing area.
            refreshFileList();

        // If file was uploaded, but we have required fields to fill out,
        // then adjust page to only show that...
        } else if (ev.state == 3) {

            ev.page.find("form")
                .children(":visible")
                    .css("display", "none")
                    .addClass("ptWasVisible")
                    .end()
                .find("input[title='Name']")
                    .closest("div[id^='WebPart']")
                        .appendTo(ev.page.find("form"));
        }

    }//end: onPageChange()
});
```

Comment: @knox2 can you close this thread by marking answer.

Answer (score 0):

Due to security concerns, you cannot access the file system from JavaScript; you can only perform web related activities (at least when ran from a web browser).

From the [JavaScript Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Security):

> JavaScript and the DOM provide the potential for malicious authors to deliver scripts to run on a client computer via the web. Browser authors contain this risk using two restrictions. First, scripts run in a sandbox in which they can only perform web-related actions, not general-purpose programming tasks like creating files.

Your only options in Office 365 are to use a provider hosted app and CSOM, or to use a flash-based tool such as [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/demos/).